# Spring boot external configuration in standalone jetty

Tags: spring-boot, jetty

I am building a spring boot application. I want to configure my database properties externally, so anyone can run war file from any machine. How do I configure application.properties externally? I am following this documentation http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

So I created a app.properties file in jetty's home directory.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://mymachine:1433;databasename=TESTDB
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.datasource.username=someuser
spring.datasource.password=somepass
```

And trying to run war file through jetty, but it is not detecting application.properties for some reason.

```
java -jar ../start.jar --spring.config.location=file:///E:/Tools/jetty-distribution-9.3.12.v20160915/demo-base/webapps/app.properties
```

When I run above command, I get following error in jetty

```
Caused by:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'driverClassName' must not be empty
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.hasText(Assert.java:168)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName(DriverManagerDataSource.java:1
24)
        at com.abc.mycompany.sts.config.settings.PersistenceContext.dataSource(PersistenceContext.java:55)
        at com.abc.mycompany.sts.config.settings.PersistenceContext$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$368bb66a.CGLIB$dataSource$2
(<generated>)
        at com.abc.mycompany.sts.config.settings.PersistenceContext$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$368bb66a$$FastClassBySpring
CGLIB$$25ca0903.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(Configurati
onClassEnhancer.java:356)
        at com.abc.mycompany.sts.config.settings.PersistenceContext$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$368bb66a.dataSource(<genera
ted>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy
.java:162)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolv
er.java:588)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(Ab
stractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutow
ireCapableBeanFactory.java:1022)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCap
ableBeanFactory.java:512)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapab
leBeanFactory.java:482)
```

This is my jetty's directory structure

```
E:\Tools\jetty-distribution-9.3.12.v20160915\demo-base\webapps
```

On command line I am starting jetty by going to demo-base and running command

```
java -jar ../start.jar --spring.config.location=file:///E:/Tools/jetty-distribution-9.3.12.v20160915/demo-base/webapps/app.properties
```

The bean looks like below where I am trying to access properties from external application.properties file

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();            
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty(ConfigConstants.DATABASE_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME));
    dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty(ConfigConstants.DATABASE_URL));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty(ConfigConstants.DATABASE_USERNAME));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty(ConfigConstants.DATABASE_PASSWORD));

    return dataSource;
}
```

This doesn't find my app.properties file. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you try spring.datasource.driverClassName (without hyphens) ?

Comment: @Lucky - That doesn't make sense since the same properties work when the properties file is inside jar

Comment: Still need more information. For example, can you show us the directory/file structure where the application.properties is supposed to reside?

Comment: @pczeus - I downloaded jetty and it is on path E:\Tools. You can see more information I added about directory from where I am trying to start jetty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see you use env properties to initialize datasource and I would suggest another one solution for you.

Proposition one: it is possible to set properties value on startup like:

```
java -jar ../start.jar --spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://mymachine:1433;databasename=TESTDB --spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver --spring.datasource.username=someuser --spring.datasource.password=somepass
```

Or if you want mask property names,  define your own properties. You have to pack following `application.properties` file into you jar:

```
spring.datasource.url=${APP_DB_URL}
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=${APP_DB_DRIVER_CLASS}
spring.datasource.username=${APP_DB_USERNAME}
spring.datasource.password=${APP_DB_PASSWORD}
```

Next. Before run application set env properties. On *nix platform:

```
export APP_DB_URL=jdbc:sqlserver://mymachine:1433;databasename=TESTDB
export APP_DB_DRIVER_CLASS=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
export APP_DB_USERNAME=someuser
export APP_DB_PASSWORD=somepass
```

On windows platform:

```
set APP_DB_URL=jdbc:sqlserver://mymachine:1433;databasename=TESTDB
set APP_DB_DRIVER_CLASS=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
set APP_DB_USERNAME=someuser
set APP_DB_PASSWORD=somepass
```

And finally, just run your jar without any params:

```
java ../start.jar
```

I hope this post could be helpful for you.

Comment: I can't include application.properties in a jar, that's why I am trying external configuration where I can run my war file on any environment

Comment: Ok, what about first proposition (--spring.datasource.url= ...), could it be helpful for you? You can override desired properties in this way.

Comment: Not sure what happened, but suddenly the first option you suggested is not working any more, I get the same error which I reported in this question

Comment: Any changes in project/versions/environment? Could you show entire start command?

Comment: Konstantin - I decided to go for approach 2, not sure why approach 1 stopped working suddenly. java -jar ../start.jar --spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://mymachine:1433;databasename=TESTDB --spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver --spring.datasource.username=someuser --spring.datasource.password=somepass

Comment: Is this constatn from your custom class: Config Constants.DATABASE_DRIVER CLASS_NAME? What is its value?

Comment: The value is spring.datasource.driver-class-name.

Answer (score 3):

Put your application.properties file under `JETTY_HOME/resources` folder and add

`--module=resources`

line to `start.ini` file.

Second one add resources folder to classpath, so every file under that directory will be in the classpath of your webapp.

This should work.

Answer (score 2):

```
--spring-config-location
```

is not the correct property name. The property uses dot-notation, not hyphens.

Try:

```
--spring.config.location
```

For more information, see section 24.3 in the documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Additionally, you should point to the directory where the application.properties will be located instead of to the specific file. That may help, but is more useful when you later want to specify profiles. Spring Boot can then select the correct properties file base on profile. For example:

```
--spring.config.location=file:///E:/jetty/demo-base/webapps/
```

If you had multiple files in this directory like:

```
application.properties
application-dev.properties 
application-prod.properties
```

You could add the

```
--spring.profiles.active=prod
```

To select the prod properties.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that now, but it still gives me same error about driverClassName must not be empty. I am populating driverClassname property from properties file

Comment: Can you update your post and also provide the stacktrace and error you are receiving?

Comment: I have only one file. It is named as app.properties instead of application.properties. Name of the file doesn't make any difference. I get the same error. If i use the same file inside my war, it works fine. Also pointing to directory instead of file, I get the same error

Answer (score 1):

You have too many slashes in the path to the file after "file:" protocol and backslashes should be used too:

> --spring.config.location=file:E:\Tools\jetty-distribution-9.3.12.v20160915\demo-base\webapps\app.properties

Comment: Are you sure about slashes? That's how it says on Spring's website